# Show all dropzone errors instead of one at a time

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, dropzone.js

When I upload a file and receive an error from the server it displays one error then removes it and then shows the next error.
How can I show all errors on the page?

Here is what I tried:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
Dropzone.options.imageDropzone = {
  maxFilesize: 512, // MB
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  init: function() {
    this.on("error", function(file, response) {      
      $('#imgError').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Filename: ' + file.name + response + '</div>'); 
      this.removeFile(file); 
    });
    this.on("success", function(file, response) {      
      result = $(response).find("#imgSuccess");
      $('#imgResults').html(result);      
    });       
  }
};
});
```

Comment: `$('#imgError').append()`